# How to put image on the opening screen of the app android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

Those images that appear before the app starts, you know? When you click to open, open a blank screen and dps opens the first activity of the app, I want to put a picture there

Comment: I think you mean a splash screen?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a splash screen is what you're trying to achieve, here's a snippet of code to start with.

1. Create a new launcher activity `SplashActivity`. Navigate to the XML `activity_splash.xml` and create the layout you want.

   ```
    <LinearLayout 
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:gravity="center">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           android:textColor="@android:color/black"
           android:text="Hello World!"
           app:drawableTopCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Navigate to the java file `SplashActivity.java` and add the following code inside the `onCreate()` (MILLIS is the time for which you want the splash screen to show, in milliseconds):

   ```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, MILLIS);
   ```

Comment: não é isso, é tipo o aplicativo do kindle, quando o app ta abrindo ele n aparece uma tela vazia, ele aparece uma imagem, desse jeito ele apareceu a tela vazia e dps iniciou a activity com essa imagem

Comment: It's quite the same thing. In your MainActivity, place an `ImageView` with the desired background image, and set the visibility for all other views to `gone`. Then, in the run() method, set the visibility to `visible`